# SDL/C++ && Operator - Lazyfoo tutorial

Tags: c++, sdl

I am learning SDL from Lazyfoo.net tutorials, In Chapter "32_text_input_and_clipboard_handling", i cant understand how the below code works correctly. (I sent mail to lazyfoo contact person, but still waiting for reply)

```
   if(!((e.text.text[0] == 'c' || e.text.text[0] == 'C') && 
   (e.text.text[0] == 'v' || e.text.text[0] == 'V') && 
   SDL_GetModState() & KMOD_CTRL))
   {
     //Append character
     inputText += e.text.text;
     renderText = true;
   }
```

This code function is to ignore/check that we're not getting a ctrl and c/v event, it is working as per the tutorial, but how ? 
there are two "&&" operators in this code which means all three conditions must be satisfied to execute the code inside the curly braces!

Which means, the code ignores

> ctrl AND c AND v as per below image

[Image Link for Ctrl + C + v (Ctrl AND c AND v)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZ5ZB.png)

instead of

> ctrl and c/v as per below image

[Image Link for Ctrl + C / v (Ctrl AND c OR v)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arEWA.png)

but some how it is working as ctrl and c/v in C++/SDL???

Comment: The if is negated. Look at De Morgans theorem

Comment: Please make your question title describe the question, instead of just listing things

Comment: What does "ctrl and c/v" mean?

Comment: Thats were my confusion is, the above code seems like Ctrl + c and Ctrl + v and then it's negated, so my doubt is that the logic should be Ctrl + c or Ctrl + v correct ?

Answer (score 0):

The if statement uses `!` for negation, if all three of the conditions are met, then the Boolean value would be true, however it is then negated giving false. Similarly, when ctrl + c/v is not being pressed, the 3 conditions would then return a Boolean value of false, which is negated to true, allowing the code within the if statement to be executed.

If you were to write this condition in english it would be: *if ctrl + c and ctrl + v are* **not** *pressed.*

Comment: Thats were my confusion is, the above code seems like Ctrl + c and Ctrl + v and then it's negated, so my doubt is that the logic should be Ctrl + c or Ctrl + v correct ?